# Draw large number (10M) of 2d polygons with opengl

Tags: opengl, graphics, 2d, cad

I'm working on a CAD software which need to show circuit blueprint containing more than 10M 2d polygons. Each polygon is simple, 95% of them are only rectangles, others have fewer than 10 vertexes.

In order to show the whole design, I will need to create a huge vertex buffer which will definitely blow up the graphics memory limit. However, since most of the polygons won't be seen clearly at that scale, I'm thinking of using some pre screening algorithm to minimize the polygons to draw. But if I do so, so many polygons (each of them won't be larger than one pixel) will be gone, then the final image will be wrong.

Another thought will be to separate polygons into groups each of which will be strongly connected (touching), then construct a large polygon for each group. Some level of detail algorithm may be used to shrink the points without changing the shapes. Not sure how fast these algorithms are and if I need to pre calculate for different scale level.

Is there any standard way to deal with this problem? I'm pretty sure it has been solved lots of times...

To clarify, we need to make this work on OpenGL 2.1.

Comment: Look into instanced rendering.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I can't really use instanced rendering, since most of the rectangles are different size. And we stuck with opengl 2.1 which doesn't support it anyway.

Comment: You can change the size of the rectangles in a vertex shader with instanced rendering.

Comment: @CyberSnoopy: what "graphics memory limit" do you think this will blow up? And even assuming that it does: you don't need to put everything into the VBO and draw with a single call. Using a few more draw calls with a reduced amount of data will also work.

Comment: Does the content change between frames? Or is it static content where the user can only pan and zoom?

Comment: @derhass By saying memory limit, I mean the largest VBO I can create. Not sure how many bytes a vertex will cost. The total will be 10M * 4 * byte_per_vetex, looks like a lot.

Comment: @RetoKoradi It's static content, but user can pan and zoom. I will pre screen the polygons not showing up in the viewport. But at whole design level, all of them will have to be counted.

Answer (score 2):

You're targeting OpenGL-2.1 so client side vertex arrays are available. Which effectively means: You don't have to upload anything to the GPU at all, the data is fetched from your programs address space on demand.

Of course 10M triangles is not a lot; some professions use programs in which a single frame ends up with 1G triangles. The amount of data required is easy enough to calculate:

```
  10M  # number of primitives
* 4    # number of vertices in a quad
* 4B   # sizeof GLfloat
* 2    # number of elements in a 2D vector

= 320MB
```

That's not a lot. Most GPUs you can buy these days come with at least 512MiB of memory, where this fits nicely. However even if your GPU doesn't have as much memory available, OpenGL's memory model is abstract and data is swapped to and from the GPU as needed.

Comment: and some drivers will be able to selectively upload to the GPU as needed